# Getting "sed error - illegal byte sequence" (in bash)

Tags: bash, sed

Doing some stream editing to change the nasty Parallels icon. It's poorly developed and embedded into the app itself rather than being an image file. So I've located this sed command that has some good feedback:

```
sudo sed -i.bak s/Parallels_Desktop_Overlay_128/Parallels_Desktop_Overlay_000/g /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_client_app
```

It returns `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Can anyone explain what this means? What part of the command is the problem?

Comment: Those coming from Google: try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23523680/510036) first. I come to this thread more times than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try setting the `LANG` environment variable (`LANG=C sed ...`) or use one of the binary sed tools mentioned here: [binary sed replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604964/binary-sed-replacement)

**Why the error?**

Without `LANG=C` sed assumes that files are encoded in whatever encoding is specified in `LANG` and the file (being binary) may contain bytes which are not valid characters in `LANG`'s encoding (thus you could get 'illegal byte sequence').

**Why does `LANG=C` work?**

C just happens to treat all ASCII characters as themselves and non-ASCII characters as literals.

Comment: If `bash` is your shell, you can enter `export LANG=C` and try again.

Comment: Great, but using `LC_ALL=C sed ...` is the more robust approach: if `LC_ALL` or `LC_CTYPE` are set (to something other than `C`), setting `LANG` will have no effect. (`LC_ALL` _overrides_ all individually set categories, if any, whereas `LANG` only takes effect for those categories _not_ explicitly set.)

Comment: To me `LANG=C` did not work but `LC_ALL=C` did

Answer (score 76):

`LANG=C` alone didn't do the trick for me but adding `LC_CTYPE=C` as well solved it.

Comment: An _effective_ value of `LC_CTYPE=C` is sufficient to solve the problem: `LC_CTYPE=C sed ...`. However, that won't work if `LC_ALL` is set (to something other than `C`), because that _overrides_ all individual `LC_*` categories. Thus, the most robust approach is to use `LC_ALL=C sed ...`.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Sierra

Answer (score 30):

In addition to `LANG=C` and `LC_CTYPE=C`, I had to do `LC_ALL=C` to get this to work.

`LC_ALL` overrides all individual `LC_*` categories. Thus, the most robust approach is to use `LC_ALL=C sed ...` - no need to also deal with the other variables.

Comment: explain it a little bit more, please

Comment: @rpax: Actually, an effective `LC_CTYPE` value of C is sufficient, so using `LC_CTYPE=C sed ...` (directly prepending to the offending command) is _normally_ sufficient, _unless_ `LC_ALL` - which _overrides_ all individual `LC_*` categories - has been set. Thus, the most robust approach is to use `LC_ALL=C sed ...` - no need to also deal with the other variables.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Hope you don't mind, I edited @mklement0's comment into the answer.

Comment: @Qix: My contribution was added as a _comment_ because I deemed it too invasive to be an edit: your edit amounts to putting words into @rjpeter2's mouth, and, in its current form, results in a somewhat self-contradictory answer. Do note that I've recommended the `LC_ALL=C sed ...` approach in comments on _all_ answers on this page, including the currently accepted one. For the complete picture, I suggest consulting my [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23584470/45375) on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 19):

I managed to do it by running:

```
unset LANG
```

before the `sed` command.

Not sure what I've done or why it works but it did.

Comment: I needed to do the above fix when following this tutorial: http://projectpoppycock.com/angularjs-phonegap-and-angular-seed-lets-go/

Comment: This removes the error, but actually solves nothing for me.

Comment: As for why it works: If your locale was initially _set_ with `[export] LANG=...` (as opposed to setting `LC_ALL` or setting `LC_*` categories individually), then unsetting `LANG` makes all `LC_*` categories revert to `"C"`; ending up with a `LC_CTYPE` value of `C` is what solves the problem. Conversely, if `LC_ALL` or even `LC_CTYPE` specifically are set to something other than `C`, your approach won't work.

Comment: @mklement0, I think your comments make a nice answer...!

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks; I actually did create an answer - not to this, but a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23584470/45375

Comment: `(unset LANG; locale)` <--- LC_CTYPE defaults to C