# Error when using 'sed' with 'find' command on OS X: "invalid command code ."

Tags: bash, macos, sed, find

Being forced to use CVS for a current client and the address changed for the remote repo. The only way I can find to change the remote address in my local code is a recursive search and replace.

However, with the sed command I'd expect to work:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/192.168.20.1/new.domain.com/" {} \;
```

I get an error for every file:

```
sed: 1: ".//file/path ...": invalid command code .
```

I've tried to escape the periods in the sed match/replacement but that doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 809, accepted):

If you are on a OS X, this probably has nothing to do with the sed command. On the OSX version of `sed`, the `-i` option expects an `extension` argument so your command is actually parsed as the `extension` argument and the file path is interpreted as the command code.

Try adding the `-e` argument explicitly and giving `''` as argument to `-i`:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/192.168.20.1/new.domain.com/" {} \;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x).

Comment: The example command you give however, gives: sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: That most probably is a copy-paste encoding problem as it works with no problem in my tests. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287564/getting-sed-error-illegal-byte-sequence-in-bash)

Comment: If you spent 10 min like I did finding the difference, it is -e option

Comment: @acheron55 I updated my answer to be explicitly about the `-e` option

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x) answers the `RE error: illegal byte sequence` on MacOS.

Comment: i used an empty string '' as the parameter for -i and that worked, like `sed -i '' 's/blah/xx/g'`

Comment: For me, adding `-e` after `-i` made `sed` backup all my files in this way: "foo.txt" -> "foo.txt-e". Obviously what I wanted was rather `-i ''`, i.e. don't backup changed files.

Comment: I definitely am on OS X default sed, not homebrew'd. Mavericks 10.9.3 (maybe sed differs with OS X versions?). No worries, I've added the answer I'd like to have had (and I guess it would have solved the OP's problem as well).

Comment: Same problem for me. This `-i -e` combined with a `find` resulted in many many files ending in `-e-e-e-e-e-e-e`.

Comment: Same here, using the sed that ships with 10.10. I recommend `-i ''`

Comment: I find it funny how you [edited your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19457213/revisions) to make it look like mine :) Anyway, as long as users solve their problems, I don't care. Cheers!

Comment: @mdup I updated my answer after your comment, which I could not verify on my system, but which was backed up by several other commenters. My edit dates Oct 1 '15 at 4:44 and your answer is dated Oct 2 '14 at 8:54. Cheers.

Comment: You can solve this, and all the other problems with macOS, by installing Gnu versions of everything

Comment: A working revised answer on OSX is:  find ./ -type f -exec sed -ie "s/192.168.20.1/new.domain.com/" {} \;

Comment: is there a version where the same command would work for both OS X and Linux?

Comment: @bentael Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) on OS X you can install the GNU `sed` which is the one installes on Linux.

Comment: @bentael if you don't want to install an alternative `sed` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux#comment85499736_22084103

Comment: Why is this upvoted 578 times? Creates many backup files ending in ".oldext-e"

Comment: Thank youuuu! Been trying to write a script for generating an app and have been searching around for the past couple of hours for this.

Answer (score 114):

On OS X nothing helps poor builtin sed to become adequate. The solution is:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

And then use gsed instead of sed, which will just work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, which worked great for me! Working on both Linux and Mac, I'd much prefer access to a familiar tool than learning arcane differences between two closely related ones.

Comment: Thanks - worked for me too. 
A nice little tip is to set up an alias like `alias sed='gsed'` to make the alignment between macOS and linux complete.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me too. Begs the question -- why is macOS `sed` different? Why? I mean, why???

Comment: @ChrisMiller, MacOS is based on BSD technology, not on GNU/Linux. Hence sed is the bsd variant.

Answer (score 68):

You simply forgot to supply an argument to `-i`. Just change `-i` to `-i ''`.

Of course that means you don't want your files to be backed up; otherwise supply your extension of choice, like `-i .bak`.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add an extension to the -i flag. This basically creates a backup file with the original file.

`sed -i.bakup  's/linenumber/number/' ~/.vimrc`

sed will execute without the error

Answer (score 3):

It is not the case for the OP but it was for me and could help someone else.

If you are using `'` to enclose regex, double check the `'` characters. I was copying and pasting the script from word processing and it was pasting `'` as `’` in bash.

Comment: The OS generally does no such thing. Did you copy/paste from a blog or a word processor or something?

Comment: @tripleee you're right! Updated my answer.

Comment: So the real lesson here is _never use a word processor for code._ There are some blog platforms which unfortunately apply "styling" to code and thus breaking it, which you as a consumer of that blog can't really do much about.

Comment: (Also, irritatingly, the keyboard substitution facility on IOS will "helpfully" replace ASCII quotes with "typographic" ones no matter what you do, so it's not great for saving snippets of code.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably your new domain contain `/` ? If so, try using separator other than `/` in `sed`, e.g. `#`, `,` etc.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's#192.168.20.1#new.domain.com#' {} \;
```

It would also be good to enclose `s///` in single quote rather than double quote to avoid variable substitution or any other unexpected behaviour