# Combine grep -v with grep -r?

Tags: grep

I want to remove an entire line of text from all files in a given directory. I know I can use `grep -v foo filename` to do this one file at a time. And I know I can use `grep -r foo` to search recursively through a directory. How do I combine these commands to remove a given line of text from all files in a directory?

Comment: `grep -rv foo directory`

Comment: I would recommend using sed

Comment: @jlhonora this works but only prints everything to terminal and doesn't overwrite the actual file.

Comment: @Sandeep do you know what the equivalent of grep -v is with sed? I looked here ( http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62m )  but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Sandeep This works on a singular file basis: `sed 's/regexp/replacement/g' inputFileName > outputFileName` but I don't know how to do this across a directory of files.

Comment: @PGilbert you'll need to combine sed with xargs. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work:

`grep -ilre 'Foo' . | xargs sed -i 'extension' 'Foo/d'`

Where `'extension'` refers to the addition to the file name. It will make a copy of the original file with the extension you designated and the modified file will have the original filename. I added -i in case you require it to be case insensitive.

modified file1 becomes "file1"
original file1 becomes "file1extension"

[invalid command code ., despite escaping periods, using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed)

One of the responses suggests that the newer version of `sed`'s `-i` option in OSX is slightly different so you need to add an extension. The file is being interpreted as a command, which is why you are seeing that error.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
grep -vlre 'foo' . | xargs sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Broken down:

```
grep:
  -v 'Inverse match'
  -l 'Show filename'
  -r 'Search recursively'
  -e 'Extended pattern search'

xargs: For each entry perform

sed -i: replace inline
```

Comment: I get the same error message as mentioned in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX command to find files is named `find`, not `grep`. Forget you ever heard of `grep -r` as it's just a bad idea, here's the right way to find files and perform some action on them:

```
find . -type f -print | xargs sed -i '/badline/d'
```

Comment: But what if you want to edit **only** the files that **don't contain** a certain keyword? That's what I understood from the question, and that's why I suggested `grep -rv`

Comment: This almost works, but I get the following error `sed: 1: "./hr1_14_s.nex": invalid command code .` where hr1_14_s.nex is the name of the file I want to search inside of. Here is a link to a test file so that maybe the error can be recreated. https://github.com/PrincessG/SignalNoise/blob/master/Testfile. I'd like to remove the entire lines containing 'alligator_mississippiensis'.

Comment: change `-i` to `-i ""` as you're apparently using a sed that requires `-i` to have an arg after it (OSX?).

Comment: @jlhonora the script I posted will only make changes to files that contain the keyword.