# Replace whitespace with colon in a datetime string for all files

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I currently run some python code to output a set of values alongside a datetime string, into approx 400 text files. The outputs have different values but the same format.

I have changed the format of the datetime string at some point to have a colon between days and hours instead of a whitespace. So now I need to edit the previous whitespace version to match the current version.
Sample :

```
2016/02/11 12:54:28 0071754407 7599 4727 2690
2016/02/11 14:07:41 0071754407 7599 4726 2690 
2016/02/11:15:26:58 0071754407 7599 4725 2690 
2016/02/11:17:12:59 0071754407 7599 4722 2690 
2016/02/11:19:01:21 0071754407 7599 4721 2690
```

I am looking at using sed [similar to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/replace-all-white-spaces-with-commas-in-a-text-file)
My current attempt looks something like so

```
find . -name '*.txt' | sed -ei 's'\d\/\d\s\d\d\:''\d\/\d\:\d\d\:g'
```

As you can see, I don't know how sed handles regex. I am also unsure about the suffixes to sed, I read that i allows to write to the same file and e is for expressions.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly noted in the comments, you cannot modify files read on `stdin`, so you will need a `while` loop fed by `find` that will allow you to operate on the *filename* of each file instead. Something similar to:

```
while read -r name; do
    sed -i 's/^\([^ ]*\)[ ]\(.*$\)/\1:\2/' "$name"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt")
```

(**note:** you can add `-i.bak` to your `-i` option to have `sed` create backup files for each file it modifies)

**Example INput**

```
$ cat file
2016/02/11 12:54:28 0071754407 7599 4727 2690
2016/02/11 14:07:41 0071754407 7599 4726 2690
```

**Output**

```
$ sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\)[ ]\(.*$\)/\1:\2/' <file
2016/02/11:12:54:28 0071754407 7599 4727 2690
2016/02/11:14:07:41 0071754407 7599 4726 2690
```

Comment: Don't pipe find output's to another command. Use the `-exec` option instead.

Comment: So I tried this with one file. `cat myfile1.txt` and then `sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\)[ ]\(.*$\)/\1:\2/' <myfile1.txt` however the output is still the same as the input.

Comment: duh... Didn't even think about it. I guess it wouldn't do much good.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did receive an error, which I quickly resolved from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed). Something something OSX.
All txt files in current directory edited but the strings that were correct now have a colon at the end of them instead of whitespace, guessing regex matched it to be changed. `2016/02/11:15:26:58:0071754407 7599 4725 2690 1497796`

Comment: I missed the part -i.bak, should definitely have used that. haha. Now to work out the regex string to reverse it.

Comment: Test this for the reversal `sed -i 's/^\(.*[:].*[:].*[:].*\)[:]\(.*\)$/\1 \2/' file` (on a couple of files before unleashing it on all of them).

Comment: Thanks, the combined use of both has had the overall desired result. Thanks very much, I'm just terrible with regex.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i -e 's_^\(..../../..\) \(..:..:..\)_\1:\2_' {} \;
```

Explanation:

The `find -exec` command will call `sed` for each filename it is identifying in the current path (`.`).

`-i` tells `sed` to modify the original input files instead of dumping its output to the standard output.

`-e` tells `sed` to use the substitution pattern provided right after it in the command line.

We used `_` as a separator for the `s` substitution command.

We freely used the *any character match* (.) to match what we assume to be the timestamp. We start at beginning of line (^) and match the two parts of the timestamp into the substitution variables \1 and \2.

(If what we find at the line will not match our pattern containing the slashes and colons, will we not touch it).

The last part, `{} \;`, is the end of the `-exec` command of our `find`. it appends the filename to the end of the `sed` command and terminates that command.