# sed invalid command code when using find to loop through files on a Mac

Tags: bash

I guess this is a simple question but I seem to be able to understand why this is incorrect.

```
#!/bin/sh
header=`cat header.txt`
find . -name "*.go" -exec sed -i "" -e "1s|^|$header|" {} \;
```

This piece of script should add the content of header.txt to all .go files. But instead it outputs: `sed: 1: "./restapi/operations/su ...": invalid command code .`

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457213/1501285) answer, but the issue is still there.

Comment: Try removing the space after `-i`

Comment: Aha, that is a step further. Now left with `sed: 1: "1s|^|/*                 ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`

Comment: probably has to do with header.txt not being read with new lines?

Comment: It would probably be easier to loop over the filenames and then `cat header.txt $filename > TEMP; mv TEMP $filename`. \[edit\] but then you'd lose the permissions.

Comment: Not sure I understand, that would go as an argument for `-e` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -name "*.go" -exec bash -c \
'cat header.txt "$1" > "$1".tmp && mv "$1".tmp "$1"' - {} \;
```

Comment: That loses any custom permissions set on the original files.

Comment: Thanks mate, this was driving me nuts, haha. I only don't understand the minus sign in the ` - {} \;`. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hyphen is a dummy placeholder to populate `$0` and `{}` is used to populate `$1`