# Error using sed with -i flag inside a bash for loop

Tags: bash, sed

I have this code:

```
for f in $(find -E . -type f ! -regex ".*(zip|png|jpeg|jar|ear|ttf|jpg|git)") ! -path .git; do echo $'\nFile: '$f; sed "$(( $(wc -l <$f) / 2 ))"',$d' $f; done
```

And it seems to be working well. The problem is that if I change it to:

```
for f in $(find -E . -type f ! -regex ".*(zip|png|jpeg|jar|ear|ttf|jpg|git)") ! -path .git; do echo $'\nFile: '$f; sed -i "$(( $(wc -l <$f) / 2 ))"',$d' $f; done
```

**Note the -i option in the sed command. I get this error:**

> sed: 1: "./some/path/ ...": invalid command code .

Comment: Try using `set -x` to see what `sed` command is actually run when it fails.

Comment: Where should I use that set instruction?

Comment: in your shell before you execute your command again. It modifies the shell to tell it to display the commands it run before running them. I expect you'll see all the executed `sed` commands. Use `set +x` to remove the option when you're done (or just close your shell, it doesn't persist)

Comment: It just says this: `sed: 1: "./my/path/ ...": invalid command code .
+ for f in '$(find -E . -type f ! -regex ".*(zip|png|jpeg|jar|ear|ttf|jpg|git)")' '!' -path .git
+ echo '`

Comment: Are you on OS X ? If so check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed) out (on OS X `-i` expects an additional parameter and will consume the command if it's not there, leading to the error you get)

Comment: Yes, I'm in OSX. will check that question, thanks

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm voting to close your question as a duplicate of the other then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid command code ., despite escaping periods, using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed)