# sed -i bash command to modify line on JSON my file (erase .png at the end)

Tags: python, json, bash, sed

I'm trying to find a way to erase the ".png" extension in this JSON file but only for the attribute (so "image": "test.png" should keep .png and "uri": "0.png" should keep it too)

But all the attribute values should be without .png at the end so the value for the background would be Yellow and not Yellow.png

Any tips about this? I tried to use sed command like:

```
sed -i 's/Yellow.png/Yellow/g' myfile.json
```

It didn't work and it's not the best way because I would have to do each attribute by hand... (I put a sample but I have more than 100 attributes)

```
{
"name": "test",
"symbol": "test",
"image": "test.png",
"properties": {
    "files": [
        {
            "uri": "0.png",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": []
},
"description": "test",
"seller_fee_basis_points": 0,
"attributes": [
    {
        "trait_type": "Head",
        "value": "1.png"
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Body",
        "value": "Big.png"
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Left Arm",
        "value": "Gun.png"
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Right Arm",
        "value": "Gun.png"
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Left Legs",
        "value": "Normal.png"
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Background",
        "value": "Yellow.png"
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Right Legs",
        "value": "Normal.png"
    }
],
"collection": {
    "name": "Test",
    "family": "test"
}
```

}

Comment: Using `sed` to modify structured data is nearly always a bad idea. Use a dedicated JSON tool  like `jq`. This is a very common FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change what comes after `"value"`, you can do the following using sed:

```
's/\(\"value\".*\).png\"/\1"/'
```

`\(\"value\".*\).png\"` matches anything starting with `"value"` and ends with `.png"`.

Then `\1"` substitutes it for the first match group (what was between the parentheses) and a double quote.

You can see the result here:
https://sed.js.org/?gist=9f1a0ce59fd9a7b46277498cc106444e

Comment: It look good but How can I pass a file in argument ? like 

sed -i 's/\(\"value\".*\).png\"/\1"/' *json 

doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried using only the file instead of "*.json"? sed -i 's/\(\"value\".*\).png\"/\1"/' a.json worked for me...

Comment: Yes I get  : sed -i 's/\(\"value\".*\).png\"/\1"/' 0.json 
sed: 1: "0.json": invalid command code .

Comment: That worked for me as well. Are you using bash?

Comment: If you're on a Mac maybe you have this problem with the "-i" option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/error-when-using-sed-with-find-command-on-os-x-invalid-command-code

Comment: I kinda find a workaround but I have to launch the command as many time as I have attributs in my file, so after spamming 100 times sed -i '' -e 's/\(\"value\".*\).png\"/\1"/' *.json. My files are good ! thanks a lot