# Executing sed from php script

Tags: php, sed, exec

I have the following lines in a php script:

```
$onecount=exec('grep -oi "STRING1" FILE1 | wc -l');
$boo=$onecount;
echo($boo);
exec("sed -i 1,20s/STRING2/$boo/ FILE2");
```

When I execute this program, it displays the number 27, which is the correct value for $onecount (and hence for $boo), i.e. the number of times that STRING1 occurs in FILE1.  I therefore expect all instances of STRING2 in the first 20 lines of FILE2 to be replaced by "27".  In fact nothing changes.

BUT:
When I change the second line above from
`$boo=$onecount;`
to, say,
`$boo=3;`
then everything works as expected:  The program both displays the number 3 AND correctly changes all instances of STRING2 in FILE2 to the string '3'.

The fact that all works as expected when I set $boo=3 tells me (I think) that there is no problem with the syntax of my sed command.

Another thing that hasn't worked: I have tried  replacing $onecount with things like strvalue($onecount), but the problem persists.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't replicate this with php 8.1 - using files containing exactly those strings and running your exact code, the change is made

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jhnc :  Now that I understand (and have successfully implemented mikey's answer), it seems surprising to me that you couldn't replicate this, and it would be interesting to understand why.   But I don't think I have the energy to try to figure that out at the moment.

Comment: freebsd (and so presumably macos) appear to follow System V style rather than [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) and format `wc -l` output like [`%7u`](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.bin/wc/wc.c?h=releng%2F8.0#n185) whereas coreutils uses [`%1u`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/d2df669c9c8fb42e310f27024b8ae3e4511f257f/src/wc.c#L223) and busybox uses [`%u`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/wc.c#n136)

Comment: when I try `exec("sed 1,20s/STRING2/ 5/ /dev/null");` php prints the sed error message on stderr . Were you discarding stderr? It's odd you didn't see that message.

Comment: your code and the answer have shell injection vulnerabilities. you could consider `escapeshellarg` instead of passing bare or single-quoted arguments

Comment: @jhnc :   I am a dabbler, not a programmer.  I write code (using vi) in a terminal window and I run that code in a browser.  I wouldn't even know where to look for error messages from sed, though I'm guessing that I'd see them if I ran the code from a command line....but in any event, I did not see the error message and didn't realize I should look for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I therefore expect all instances of STRING2 in the first 20 lines of FILE2 to be replaced by "27"

If that is the case, then you should call `trim` on the output of your first `exec` command:

```php
$onecount = exec('grep -oi "STRING1" FILE1 | wc -l');
$boo = trim($onecount);
```

Otherwise there will be whitespace at the front of the string:

```php
var_dump($boo)
```

->
`string(8) "      27"`

As you can see, there are whitespace characters at the front of this string, which it sounds like you do not want.

This is actually the reason why your script works when you manually set `$boo` to `3` - the whitespace at the front is causing sed to fail to run, yielding a message like this:

`sed: 1: "1,20s/STRING2/": unterminated substitute in regular expression`

To prevent against this issue in the event you **did** want to have whitespace at the beginning, is to wrap the regex in apostrophes:

```php
exec("sed -i '1,20s/STRING2/$boo/' FILE2");
```

Or if you are on a mac:

```php
exec("sed -i -e '1,20s/STRING2/$boo/' FILE2");
```

If we put this altogether it gives me:

```php
<?php

    $onecount = exec('grep -oi "STRING1" FILE1 | wc -l');
    $boo = trim($onecount);

    var_dump($boo);

    exec("sed -i '1,20s/STRING2/$boo/' FILE2");

    # for mac - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457213/3080207
    //exec("sed -i -e '1,20s/STRING2/$boo/' FILE2");
```

Which seems to match the intent if I'm to understand your original question.

Comment: This worked.  I would never have thought of it in a million years.  Thank you so very much.