# Replace string with spaces recursively using sed on Mac

Tags: bash, magento, sed

Declaring bankruptcy after an hour trying to solve this. Here's the question:

I have a folder with 15,000 files (Magento). I want to change all copyright dates from 2013 to 2012 so I can get a legitimate diff between releases. I'm trying to use sed, based on this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282

This command is working:

```
cd path/to/project
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/2013/2012/g'
```

Except, I obviously can't trust that 2013 only applies to dates. The full string in Magento's DocBlocks is:

```
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
```

I'm trying to rewrite the sed expression to use "(c) 2013 Magento" as the string, but I'm getting the error:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

Obviously, something needs to be escaped but I can't find any applicable examples. I am not a bash-wizard by any means.

What's the correct format for this segment of the expression?

```
's/(c) 2013 Magento/(c) 2012 Magento/g'
```

Comment: Possible alternative: https://gist.github.com/kalenjordan/6766591

Comment: Does your file have literally "(c)" or ©?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11287564/1126841

Comment: Yes, it's (c) not a special character.

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously, something needs to be escaped but I can't find any applicable examples. I am not a bash-wizard by any means

Whatever sort of wizard you are, you've sent the Stack Overflow dwarfs into Mirkwood.  Your problem isn't the command escaping.  The following will run fine.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/2013 Magento Inc./2012 Magento Inc./g'
```

Test this by running it in an empty directory.

```
$ mkdir tmp-gandalf
$ cd tmp-gandalf
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/2013 Magento Inc./2012 Magento Inc./g'
```

If you had a shell escaping problem, your system would complain about it here.

Here's the problem.  The first part of your command **finds** all the files to operate on

```
find . -type f -print0
```

Using `-type f` finds **all** the files. Including non-text files.  The `sed` command doesn't like non-text files.  Try something like this

```
sed -i '' 's/2013 Magento Inc./2012 Magento Inc./g' /path/to/some.gif
find . -name '*.php' -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.phtml'
```

Where `/path/to/some.gif` is a binary file.  You'll see your `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` error.  That's `sed` saying "wtf, I'm not as clumsy or random as a blaster. I come from a more civilized age where everything was ASCII".

This [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287564/getting-sed-error-illegal-byte-sequence-in-bash) question has a slightly hacky work around (jiggering the `LANG` attribute).  I don't know enough to trust if this is a good idea or not.

My personal approach would be to limit your `find` such that only files with certain extensions are included.  You can specify multiple name patterns with the `-o` option.  So something like this

```
//NOTE: each -o needs its own -print0
find . -name '*.php' -print0 -o -name '*.xml' -print0 -o -name '*.phtml' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/2013 Magento Inc./2012 Magento Inc./g'
```

Would search `.php`, `.xml`, and `.phtml` files. You could add `js` files with another `-o -name '*.js'`.  There should only be a handful of file types in the Magento code base with Copyright notices.

Comment: The binary file issue makes perfect sense, and thank you for using proper LOTR/SW phrasing so I would understand. Running your final command with multiple name params does execute, but the replacement isn't being written into the files. I understand that's what "sed -i" param is meant to do, but it doesn't seem to be having that effect. I also tried adding {} onto the end (I think this pipes the file list from the "find" command into "sed" but that had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add -e so your command would look something like this  find . -name "*.xml" -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/RegEx/Replacement/g' {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed:

```
 sed 's/\(©\) 2013 \(Magento\)/\1 2012 \2/g'
```

Comment: Can you try: **`sed 's/2013.*\(Magento\)/2012 \1/g'`**

Comment: May I know what is your sed version? Since `sed 's/2013.*\(Magento\)/2012 \1/g'` doesn't have any unicode character

Answer (score 0):

> find /full/path/to/magento -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/(c)
>   2013 Magento/(c) 2012 Magento/g'

However:

> grep -lir -e '2013 Magento' /full/path/to/magento
>   /full/path/to/magento/app/code/core/Enterprise/Enterprise/etc/config.xml
>   /full/path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml
>   /full/path/to/magento/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Page.csv
>   /full/path/to/magento/errors/default/page.phtml
>   /full/path/to/magento/errors/enterprise/page.phtml
>   /full/path/to/magento/downloader/template/footer.phtml
>   /full/path/to/magento/downloader/template/install/footer.phtml

These files will still have "&copy; 2013 Magento" placed in the files

This should work:

> find /full/path/to/magento -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/2013
>   Magento/2012 Magento/g'

Comment: Nope. Getting this error: sed: 1: "./.!14184!.DS_Store": invalid command code .

Comment: From this command: find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/2013 Magento/2012 Magento/g'

Comment: Sorry .. "on Mac" Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply escaping the parentheses seems to work for me:

```
$ sed 's/\(c\) 2013 Magento/\(c\) 2012 Magento/g' <<< "@copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)"
@copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
```