# How to generate a random number between two limits in bash without using shuf or sort -R

Tags: bash, random

I need to generate a random number between 1981 and 2012 (inclusive) in bash. I don't have access to shuf or sort -R, and I have tried:

```
floor=1981
range=2012
while [ "$number" -le $floor ]; 
do 
number=$RANDOM; 
let "number %= range"; 
done
```

and

```
while [ "$number" -le $floor ]; 
do 
number=$(( ( RANDOM % 2012 )  + 1 )); 
done
```

However these always returns 1992:

```
echo $number
1992
```

Has anyone got any other suggestions. Ideally, just for your information, and it may not be possible, I would like it to return each number between 1981 and 2012 exactly once within a loop. For the moment though I just need to know how to generate a random number between two limits in bash, without using shuf or sort -R.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random number between range in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673830/random-number-between-range-in-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo $(( (RANDOM % 32) + 1981 ))
1991
$ echo $(( (RANDOM % 32) + 1981 ))
2000
$ echo $(( (RANDOM % 32) + 1981 ))
1998
```

To emit each only once, you need an array:

```
  declare -A emitted
  ${emitted[$number]:-false} || {
    emitted[$number]=true
    echo $number
  }
```

so if that first expression is not working for you, you have a BASH problem.
A "few" details left as an exercise for the reader.